# what type of mapping is this?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

With the `hibernate mapping` file as shown :

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojo.Ghazal" table="ghazal">
        <id name="s_no">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="poem" />
        <property name="poet" />
        <map name="map" table="linked">
            <key column="s_no" />
            <index column="key_" type="string" />
            <element column="val_" type="string" />
        </map>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

what type of mapping it is ?

The `pojo` named `ghazal` has the following properties :

- s_no
- poem
- poet
- map

I have heard many types of mapping like many to one, one to one, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is an association done with collection(Map named "map" in your case) of values, relationship is Many to many, you can find the detailed docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues)

Comment: Sorry mistyped it, relationship is One to Many.. In your case for s_no there will be multiple key_ and val_. Also while using collection elements like List or Map it will always be One to Many